# Link Error with selfmade Lib

Tags: c++, static-linking

We are trying to build a Editor for our Game Engine and so we made a lib from the Engine und link that in the Editor Proj.
The Path for the Lib and the Include Dir are remarked in the Proj. prop.
I tryed it with and without WinAPI but the Link Error still remains.
The Functions which are defined directly in the Header work, but the functions which are defined in the c++ files are creating the link errors. To i have to add the .cpp files in the Proj., isn't the lib exactly for that? -.-

OS: Windows 7 64Bit

Visual Studio 2010

```
#include "pch.h"

Application* g_pApp = NULL;

INT WINAPI WinMain( __in HINSTANCE hInstance, __in_opt HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, __in LPSTR lpCmdLine, __in int nShowCmd )
{
BlocoApp blocoApp(&g_pApp);

// start engine
Editor mainForm;
if(!g_pApp->Init(L"Bloco", 1600, 900, true, hInstance))
{
    g_pApp->Exit();
    return 1;
}

// main loop
DXUTMainLoop();

g_pApp->Exit();

return 0;
}
```

The Compiler Error:

```
error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: bool __thiscall Application::Init(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >,unsigned int,unsigned int,bool,struct HINSTANCE__ *,struct HWND__ *)" (?Init@Application@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@II_NPAUHINSTANCE__@@PAUHWND__@@@Z)".
```

Comment: Maybe you can share some code?  Also the specific error message the linker gives you.

Comment: Please post the actual errors (copy-n-paste). A bit of the source for a function having the problem (and a call site) would probably be helpful, too. I'm amazed at how many times this kind of thing needs to be asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Path for the Lib ... are remarked in the Proj. prop

I suspect that you've configured the directory where the library is in the project's "Additional Library Directories" setting.  That configures locations where the linker will look for library files it's been told to look for.

However, you also need to tell the linker to actually include the library as an input file.  This is done in the IDE using the "Input/Additional Dependencies" property.

Comment: In the pch.h Header its added with pragma comment(lib,"bloco.lib") there is also the #include<bloco.h>. My sentence is definitely incorrect gg

Comment: @MathiasHölzl: Oh - the `pragma` should do the trick.  What gets output if you do: `dumpbin /symbols bloco.lib | find "Init"`? (It's probably best to paste the results into the question - comments won't format it very well I think).

Comment: Where do i need to put this command in? I tried it with the linker command-line, but it puts out that this command is undefined.

Comment: Open a command window from the Start Menu under the "Visual Studio Tools" folder, or on the "Tools" menu in the IDE (but I may have added that one myself - I'm not sure if it's in the IDE menu by default). Rn the command in the directory where `bloco.lib' is.

Comment: I can't get it to work. When i run this command i just get an error that a dll is missing. i also tried to copy the lib in the vc/bin/ and then run the cmd...

Comment: No advices??

I think a dll could solve the problem but its so much afford to add the export macro tho everything.

Comment: @MathiasHölzl: Try "`link /dump`" instead of "`dumpbin`".  You need to do this command in a console window that's set up for the compiler (in other words that has the PATH and other environment variables set up with `vsvars32.bat` or similar).  If you enter just the command "`link /dump`" it should give you a list of options and a line that says something like, "`Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01`" - does that work? And to set expectations in advance - I'll be having limited SO access this weekend.

Comment: @ Michael Burr:  I just downloaded a simple prog. to view a Lib and it works well for any lib except of my bloco.lib (It crashes)

Comment: I created a new project and now i works :S Thanks for all the help specially to Michael Burr.